# How to set deployment repository in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, deployment, pom.xml

everybody!
When I deploy my artefact, I run

```
clean deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=releases::default::http://nexus.******.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases
```

What should I put into pom.xml to be able to run this command from Idea without creating custom command on every maschine?

Comment: You should configure the distributionManagement correctly. Afterwards you can simply do `mvn clean deploy`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>internal.repo</id>
      <name>MyCo Internal Repository</name>
      <url>Host to Company Repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Here you can find description of parameters you pass:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

Authentication you should store in your settings.xml file:

```
<server>
  <id>internal.repo</id>
  <username>maven</username>
  <password>foobar</password>
</server>
```